# How to generate mnemonics from a random number?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

How do I generate 25/13 mnemonics from a random number?

I know how to generate Bitcoin style mnemonics with BIP39 (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). However, Monero seems not using BIP-39 convention...

Is there any guidance that I can consult?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is the only documentation I'm aware of for this. See [bytes_to_words](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6b2b1d6368f5164b5354cd5826edd09c4de00cad/src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp#L382) in electrum-words.cpp. Every 4 bytes of the number (which is just taken as a byte array), converts to 3 words:

```
    w[0] = SWAP32LE(*(const uint32_t*)(src + (i * 4)));

    w[1] = w[0] % word_list_length;
    w[2] = ((w[0] / word_list_length) + w[1]) % word_list_length;
    w[3] = (((w[0] / word_list_length) / word_list_length) + w[2]) % word_list_length;
```

Where `w[1]`, `w[2]` and `w[3]` are indexes to words in the selected language `word_list`.