# How function bytes_to_words() works?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

Here are codes in function bytes_to_words():

```
w[0] = SWAP32LE(*(const uint32_t*)(src + (i * 4)));
w[1] = w[0] % word_list_length;
...
words += word_list[w[1]];
```

Then I try a case whose mnemonics are:

```
gesture mouth bids aglow tudor bawled insult listen jewels sugar calamity alley obvious sovereign jubilee legion oyster gumball using payment gumball giving sedan splendid giving
```

And the Seed should be:

```
688b988f7de513383daa61f282807fe5aabe71a639aa58b9cb6beab6f5f80a0c
```

I'd like to generate first mnemonics "gesture" with seed above so I calculate `688b988f mod 1626` and get 1441 which is not right index of wordlist...

Is there anything wrong with the process?

Comment: Is the endianness accounted for?

Comment: @koe You got the point! I mistook the endianness.
Mine is bigendian and I thought it was littleendian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example, taking your seed number:

```
688b988f7de513383daa61f282807fe5aabe71a639aa58b9cb6beab6f5f80a0c
```

Then byte swapped (and split):

```
8f988b68 3813e57d f261aa3d e57f8082 a671beaa b958aa39 b6ea6bcb 0c0af8f5
```

The first 4 bytes are:

```
8f988b68
```

Which as decimal is:

```
2409139048
```

Then:

```
2409139048 mod 1626 = 538 = words[538] = gesture
```

Which (following on from [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11976/7493)), is the first of the 3 words (**gesture**, mouth, bids), generated from the 4 bytes `8f988b68`.